# Проблемы с форматированными строками в jquery

Tags: html, jquery

При работе с JQuery возник ряд вопросов. Почему вот это:

```
subactivity_option += `<option value=${b}>` + b + "</option>";
```

на выходе даёт

```
<option value="${b}">Переменная</option>
```

А это

```
activity_option += "<option value=" +b + ">" + b + "</option>";
```

```
<option value="Переменная">Переменная</option>
```

Comment: на выходе даёт `<option value="${b}">...` - не дает

Comment: У меня b - параметр в функции $.each(subactivity, function (a, b) {...

Comment: И вот с ним не работает. А если переопределить как константу, то работает. Вопрос

Comment: И вот с ним работает.

Answer (score 0):

В том коде, который у Вас выполняется, строка ограничена не `back-tick`-ами, а обычными кавычками. Возможно, изменения JS не загрузились в браузер.

```js
const subactivity = ['abc', 'def', 'hij'];
let subactivity_option = '';
$.each(subactivity, function (a, b) {
  subactivity_option += `<option value=${b}>` + b + "</option>\n";
});
console.log(subactivity_option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Это работает. Но если b брать из параметров функции $.each(subactivity, function (a, b) {.,  то работает именно так, как я описал.

Comment: @RomanBolshevik Не работает так, как Вы описали.